# Can I add two citations for R package (One for package, one for article) at the same time in one citation file?

Tags: r, package, cran, citations

After I use `sethis::use_citation()` to create a citation file for R package.

It shows the template as below

```
citHeader("To cite package_name in publications use:")

citEntry(
  entry    = "Article",
  title    = ,
  author   = ,
  journal  = ,
  year     = ,
  volume   = ,
  number   = ,
  pages    = ,
  url      = ,
  textVersion = paste(

  )
)
```

However, I want to citation for both **package itself** and **package related article**, should I just create another similar template for **package itself** follow by? Such as

```
citHeader("To cite package_name in publications use:")

citEntry(
  entry    = "Article",
  title    = ,
  author   = ,
  journal  = ,
  year     = ,
  volume   = ,
  number   = ,
  pages    = ,
  url      = ,
  textVersion = paste(

  )
)

citEntry(
  entry    = "Manual",
  title    = ,
  author   = ,
  journal  = ,
  year     = ,
  volume   = ,
  number   = ,
  pages    = ,
  url      = ,
  textVersion = paste(

  )
)
```

Also, actually I have another format but which is not the template for this R automatically created. Anyone know if I can use that

```
@Manual{package_name,
    title = {{package_name}: },
    author = {},
    year = {},
    note = {},
    url = {},
  } 
  @Article{,
  author  = {},
  journal = {},
  title   = {{package_name}: },
  year    = {},
  volume  = {},
  number  = {}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. There are plenty of precedents. For example the [CITATION file for out Rcpp](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/CITATION) package has two articles and a book.

And you could just do something like this *on your system* to find the ten largest files you have installed:

```
edd@rob:~$ ls -Srl /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/*/CITATION | tail -10
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 50 2562 Apr 26 17:50 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/spam/CITATION
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 50 2614 Apr 26 17:55 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/strucchange/CITATION
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 50 2653 Apr 26 17:56 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RProtoBuf/CITATION
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 50 2878 Apr 26 17:45 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/stabs/CITATION
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 50 2900 Apr 26 17:44 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/colorspace/CITATION
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 50 3471 Apr 26 17:45 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/statmod/CITATION
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 50 3957 Jun 16 08:32 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/party/CITATION
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 50 4352 Aug  6 10:36 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/mboost/CITATION
-rwxrwxr-x 1 1000 50 4367 Apr 26 17:44 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/DEoptim/CITATION
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 50 4835 Apr 30 21:56 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/VGAM/CITATION
edd@rob:~$
```